# Apache server managing multiple domains with and without SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I have a bit of a head scratching issue here.

I have 2 domains, say for example:

https://domain1.com
http://domain2.com

Fact1: that domain1 has SSL enabled on it but domain2 doesn't. To cut the long story short, domain2 is expiring soon and will not be renewed so no purchase of a cert.

Fact2: domain1 has a redirect rule that enforces https on that domain

No, a wildcard is not an acceptable solution :)

so when people go to http://domain2.com all works fine, but when they go to https://domain2.com then get a SSL error and they are redirected to domain1.com, and that's basically the problem here.

How do I configure my apache virtualhosts so https is enforced on domain1 but normal http is enforced on domain2 ?

Edit: As requested, my Apache configuration:

so that's the first domain:

< VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:443 >

```
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"

    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1
    ServerName domain1

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1/public

    <Directory "/var/www/domain1/public">
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog /var/www/domain1/log/ssl-error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/domain1/log/ssl-access_log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCompression Off
    SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!DES-CBC3-SHA

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/star_domain1.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/star_domain1.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/DigiCertCA.crt
```

< /VirtualHost >

and the second domain:

< VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80 >

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain2.com
    ServerName domain2.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/public

    LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog /var/www/domain2.com/log/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/domain2.com/log/access_log combined
```

< /VirtualHost >

Thank you!

Comment: please, post your current configuration like `<VirtualHost *:80>` and so on. Maybe .htaccess also.

Comment: how do I do that ? it doesn't look like I can edit my question..

Comment: below the light blue tags for the post are light gray `share edit delete flag`

Comment: ah! Thank you :)

Comment: Why not get a letsencrypt certificate to use until domain2 is no longer renewed?